# julia parametric type with user define type

Tags: julia

Say I have a parametric type:

```
type MyType{T}
     var1
end
```

In the most of the case T is a simple integer, and there is no problem with that. However, sometimes T is an instance of an singleton type, like:

```
type Joker end
```

Thus I would like to instantiate `MyType{Joker()}(4)` but I have the following error message:

```
ERROR: type: apply_type: in MyType, expected Type{T<:Top}, got Joker
```

Reading this message, I understand that the parameters of the types have to be define "at the top"... This seems true while `MyType{MyType{4}(3)}(2)` throw a similar error message.

In the documentation : http://julia.readthedocs.org/en/latest/manual/types/#man-parametric-types there is no mention of such a restriction (or I didn't find it!).

How can I make `MyType{Joker()}(4)` work the way I want ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer here: https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/julia-users/gwgj_Mne2eY

There is two solutions:

- use the type Joker instead of the instance Joker() : `MyType{Joker}(3)`,
- or make the Joker type immutable `immutable Joker end`
  and then use `MyType{Joker()}(3)`.

Since there is no field in the `Joker` type, I think it's more practical is the first one.